# How can I parse this JSON Data in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, json

I tried to parse this JSON Data.
But I couldn't parse this JSON Data.
If anyone know about this, please let me know.

My code and JSON data are followings.

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:m_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
responseString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
[m_responseData release];

NSError *error;
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
NSArray *aryData = (NSArray *)[jsonParser objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
```

But I can't get this JSON Data with array.

> [
>
> {PropertyId: '564', Title: '5 bedroom 2 storey s/f villa',
>   Description: '5 bedroom villa 2 storey semifurnished. beautifull
>   garden,common swimming pool and gym.', Price: '1,500', CurrencyId:
>   'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'No',
>   PriceInclusiveLookup: '', House: '', Building: '', Road: '', Block:
>   '', AreaId: 'Janabiya', CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '',
>   PropertyTypeId: '', Bedrooms: '5', Bathrooms: '5', FloorSize: '',
>   LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'No', CommunalPool: 'Yes', Parking: 'Yes',
>   Furnished: 'No', AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '',
>   ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference: '', UserId: 'jahan (Arabian East
>   Properties)', Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '00973 33934656',
>   DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified: '08-Oct-2011
>   13:21:32', RawUserId: '18'} ,  {PropertyId: '565', Title: '4 bedroom
>   semifurnished villa', Description: '4 bedroom semi furnished villa.2
>   storey with maid's room'mature garden.excellent facilities.',
>   Price: '1,500', CurrencyId: 'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month',
>   PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '', House: '', Building:
>   '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Janabiya', CountryId: 'Bahrain',
>   Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms: '4', Bathrooms: '4',
>   FloorSize: '', LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'No', CommunalPool: 'Yes',
>   Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No', AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes',
>   Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference: '', UserId: 'jahan
>   (Arabian East Properties)', Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '00973
>   33934656', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified:
>   '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '18'} ,  {PropertyId: '566', Title:
>   '2 br FF pent house', Description: 'A modern luxurious 2 br pent house
>   at a prime location in Regent Tower Juffair now available for
>   rent.\r\nFor more info call 39922445 or 17291969.', Price: '900',
>   CurrencyId: 'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'Yes',
>   PriceInclusiveLookup: 'Inclusive', House: '', Building: '', Road: '',
>   Block: '', AreaId: 'Jufair', CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '',
>   PropertyTypeId: 'Apartment', Bedrooms: '2', Bathrooms: '', FloorSize:
>   '', LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'No', CommunalPool: 'Yes', Parking:
>   'Yes', Furnished: 'Yes', AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '',
>   ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference: 'j2brt', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO',
>   Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32',
>   DateModified: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId:
>   '567', Title: '4 br Villa in Sehla', Description: 'A luxurious and
>   spacious 4 br villa in Sehla now available for sale.\r\nFor more info
>   call 39-922-445 or 17-291-969.', Price: '230,000', CurrencyId: 'BHD',
>   PriceUnitId: '', PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '',
>   House: '', Building: '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Qadam',
>   CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms:
>   '4', Bathrooms: '3', FloorSize: '350', LotSize: '270', PrivatePool:
>   'No', CommunalPool: 'No', Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No',
>   AirConditioning: 'No', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For
>   Sale', Reference: 'Sh4230', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO', Phone: '', Fax: '',
>   Mobile: '', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified:
>   '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId: '568', Title:
>   '5 br SF Villa in Al Dar', Description: 'A stylish and luxurious 5 br
>   SF villa in Al Dar Jasrah with excellent facilities including a
>   private pool now avaiable for rent.\r\nFor more info call 39922445 or
>   17291969.', Price: '3,300', CurrencyId: 'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '', House: '', Building:
>   '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Jasrah', CountryId: 'Bahrain',
>   Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms: '5', Bathrooms: '6',
>   FloorSize: '734', LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'Yes', CommunalPool:
>   'Yes', Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No', AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym:
>   'Yes', Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference: 'Aldar5a',
>   UserId: 'EVFAKHRO', Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '', DateCreated:
>   '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32',
>   RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId: '569', Title: '5 br SF Villa in Al
>   Dar', Description: 'A Prestigious and stylish 5 br SF villa in Al Dar
>   Jasrah with excellent facilities now available for rent with private
>   pool BD 2500 and without private pool BD 2400.\r\nFor more info call
>   39922445 or 17291969.', Price: '2,500', CurrencyId: 'BHD',
>   PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '',
>   House: '', Building: '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Jasrah',
>   CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms:
>   '5', Bathrooms: '6', FloorSize: '530', LotSize: '', PrivatePool:
>   'Yes', CommunalPool: 'Yes', Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No',
>   AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For
>   Rent', Reference: 'Aldar5b', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO', Phone: '', Fax: '',
>   Mobile: '', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified:
>   '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId: '570', Title:
>   '4 br SF villa in Al Dar', Description: 'A luxurious 5 br SF villa in
>   Al Dar Jasarah with excellent facilities available for rent BD 2400
>   with private pool and BD 2200 without private pool.\r\nFor more info
>   call 39922445 or 17291969.', Price: '2,400', CurrencyId: 'BHD',
>   PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '',
>   House: '', Building: '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Jasrah',
>   CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms:
>   '4', Bathrooms: '5', FloorSize: '600', LotSize: '', PrivatePool:
>   'Yes', CommunalPool: 'Yes', Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No',
>   AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For
>   Rent', Reference: 'Aldar4c', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO', Phone: '', Fax: '',
>   Mobile: '', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified:
>   '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId: '571', Title:
>   '5 br SF villa Durrat Al Bahrain', Description: 'A very
>   stylish,spacious and luxurious 5 br SF villa in Durrat Al Bahrain
>   available now for rent.\r\nFor more info call 39922445 or 17291969.',
>   Price: '2,400', CurrencyId: 'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month',
>   PriceInclusive: 'No', PriceInclusiveLookup: '', House: '', Building:
>   '', Road: '', Block: '', AreaId: 'Durrat Al Bahrain', CountryId:
>   'Bahrain', Location: '', PropertyTypeId: 'House', Bedrooms: '5',
>   Bathrooms: '5', FloorSize: '1,000', LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'Yes',
>   CommunalPool: 'No', Parking: 'Yes', Furnished: 'No', AirConditioning:
>   'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '', ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference:
>   'DB5sf', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO', Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '',
>   DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', DateModified: '08-Oct-2011
>   13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'} ,  {PropertyId: '572', Title: 'Fully
>   furnished apartments', Description: 'Modern fully furnished apartments
>   with nice facilities now available for rent 2 br BD 750 / 3 br BD
>   1000.\r\nFor more info call 39922445 or 17291969.', Price: '1,000', CurrencyId: 'BHD', PriceUnitId: 'Month', PriceInclusive: 'Yes',
>   PriceInclusiveLookup: 'Inclusive', House: '', Building: '', Road: '',
>   Block: '', AreaId: 'Um Al Hassam', CountryId: 'Bahrain', Location: '',
>   PropertyTypeId: 'Apartment', Bedrooms: '3', Bathrooms: '', FloorSize:
>   '', LotSize: '', PrivatePool: 'No', CommunalPool: 'Yes', Parking:
>   'Yes', Furnished: 'Yes', AirConditioning: 'Yes', Gym: 'Yes', Year: '',
>   ListingTypeId: 'For Rent', Reference: '23bru', UserId: 'EVFAKHRO',
>   Phone: '', Fax: '', Mobile: '', DateCreated: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32',
>   DateModified: '08-Oct-2011 13:21:32', RawUserId: '10'}
>
> ]

Comment: does the error-variable contain an error?..

Answer (score 2):

You need to check JSON reposne. Before parsing, you need to check whether the given JSON string is Valid or not.

You can test it over here : http://json.parser.online.fr/

And it should follow some standard format, the paser would automatically parse the Data.

Comment: Then, This is an array of object. Android parse this data well using JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

you json data contain error

please check yoour json data are valid or not through

[Json Editor](http://braincast.nl/samples/jsoneditor/)

regards

nikhil dhamsaniya